# Angular switch when not working

Tags: angularjs, switch-statement, directive

I am trying to make a simple **switch when** statement in my Angular template and the switch statement output must be "**You're a user**" but it says that I am a guest.

What is wrong with my code?

```
<p><strong>Current role</strong></p>
<p>{{ app.currentUser.role }}</p>
<p><strong>Role to compare with</strong></p>
<p>{{ app.userRoles.user }}</p>
```

**output:**

```
Current role
user

Role to compare with
user
```

## Switch statement

```
<div ng-switch on="app.currentUser.role">
  <div ng-switch-when="app.userRoles.admin">You're admin.</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="app.userRoles.moderator">You're moderator.</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="app.userRoles.user">You're a user.</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>You're a guest.</div>
</div>
```

**output:**

```
You're a guest.
```

**Angular controller:**

```
function MainController() {
    my = this;

    my.currentUser = { role : 'user'};
    my.userRoles = { user : 'user' };

  }
```

**Plunker link:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/oCKVTjfTwkwYO9UVQU6X?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs for `ngSwitch`:

> Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match against. For example, `ng-switch-when="someVal"` will match against the string `"someVal"` not against the value of the expression `$scope.someVal`.

It looks like you won't be able to match against `app.userRoles.**` as you currently are. If you use something like:

```
<div ng-switch-when="user">You're a user.</div>
```

You should get the desired result.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Answer (score 2):

Your template should be like the below,

```
<div ng-switch on="app.currentUser.role">
  <div ng-switch-when="admin">You're admin.</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="moderator">You're moderator.</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="user">You're a user.</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>You're a guest.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any switch statement.

```
<div ng-if="app.currentUser.role">
  <div>You're {{app.currentUser.role}}.</div>
</div>

<div ng-if="!app.currentUser.role">
  <div>You're a guest.</div>
</div>
```